# Cannot open new chrome tab by `(browse-url "chrome://newtab")`

Tags: web-browser

I can open a web page by `(browse-url "http://www.google.com")`, but cannot open new tab by `(browse-url "chrome://newtab")`.  Any workaround? I would like to have an Emacs shortcut to open a new chrome tab (on Mac and on Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```el
(defun browse-url-mac-chrome (url &optional _new-window)
  "Browse URL in Chrome.

Chrome protocol URL such as chrome://newtab is supported,
unlike `browse-url-default-macosx-browser'."
  (interactive (browse-url-interactive-arg "URL: "))
  (do-applescript
   (mapconcat
    #'identity
    ;; https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271709/132365
    `("set myLink to \"" ,url "\""
      "tell application \"Google Chrome\""
      "    activate"
      "    tell front window to make new tab at after (get active tab) with properties {URL:myLink}"
      "end tell")
    "\n")))
```

The AppleScript code is from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271709/132365, since I don't know how to use that language.

Comment: It works for mac, thanks!  Is there any similar command works for Linux?

Comment: @AhLeung I don't know. I don't have a Linux computer.

Answer (score 2):

`(shell-command "chrome about:blank")` will come close to doing what you want in a cross-platform manner; the only problem is that the URL bar won't be focused. Unfortunately, `chrome chrome://newtab` opens in a new window.

[This Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893638/terminal-command-to-open-new-chromium-tab) suggests `xdotool search --onlyvisible --classname 'google-chrome' windowactivate --sync key --clearmodifiers --window 0 ctrl+t`; on my system this does exactly what you'd like.  Only works on Linux, though.